# event.preventDefault() is not working in IE 11 for custom events

Tags: internet-explorer, polymer, custom-event

I have a polymer element which triggers a custom event synchronously and I want to know whether the event was cancelled using event.preventDefault(). Using event.defaultPrevented I can know the intended action. This works on all browsers(Chrome, Canary, Firefox, Opera) but on IE 11 (not worried about older browsers) its not working.
I know I can set some property on my event and check for that back where I am triggering and handle but want to know if there is something else which I missed.

You can try out the code from 
http://jsbin.com/husamupi/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it with the following hack:

```
var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
event.initCustomEvent('custom', true, true, {});
event.preventDefault = function () {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "defaultPrevented", {get: function () {return true;}});
};
event.preventDefault();
event.defaultPrevented; // true
```

Comment: don't forget to call the original preventDefault() before defining the property - otherwise the property will be set, but the event not actually be prevented:
var origPreventDefault = event.preventDefault();
event.preventDefault = function () {
origPreventDefault();
...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like IE 11 does not set `defaultPrevented` for "synthetic" events created by code.

Example JSbin: http://jsbin.com/wohafoyo/1/edit

No matter what I tried in terms of event creation and dispatching, I could not make a synthetic click event's `preventDefault` set `defaultPrevented` to true.

Perhaps Polymer could modify `CustomElement.prototype.preventDefault` to set `defaultPrevented`.

Comment: Even if Polymer overrides CustomElement.prototype.preventDefault we cannot set defaultPrevented directly since its a read only property. What I have done currently is doing a monkey patch like: preventDefault = window.CustomEvent.prototype.preventDefault;
    window.CustomEvent.prototype.preventDefault = function () {        
      preventDefault.apply(this, arguments);
      this.isDefaultPrevented = true;      
    };

Comment: It is probably configurable. You may be able to monkeypatch with `Object.defineProperty(customEvent, 'defualtPrevented', {value: true})`