# In explorer prevent default is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

After click on li element I want to do something instead of redirect. This code works perfectly in all modern browsers, but not in explorer. In ie after click it will redirect me.

What should I add to code, if I want the same function in explorer?

HTML

```
<li class="activate-modal">
  <a href="/test.com">Some Text</a>
</li>
```

JS/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  showModal();
}

function showModal() {
  $(document).on('click', '[class*="activate-modal"]', openModal);
}

function openModal(e) {
  e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
  e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;

  //some other code
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but this may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349191/event-preventdefault-is-not-working-in-ie-11-for-custom-events

Comment: I know you said this code is working in all other browsers. But as it is, you're not calling `showModal()` function anywhere, which is what binds the click handler. I tried it after calling `showModal()` and it worked fine for me in IE11 also.

Comment: have you tried adding `someClass` on `a` tag. Instead of on `li`?

Comment: I have this html on more places and somewhere is it on <a> and on other places on <li>

Comment: @Martin54 ok. But you can still try if this works in any one place. Because I think the redirection is triggered on clicking the `a` tag and you are doing `preventDefault` only for `li`'s click handler.

Answer (score 2):

you have to attache event handler to the `link` rather than `li`   and remove `href` url from the link to stop redirecting

```
   <li>
      <a href="#" class="someClass">Some Text</a>
    </li>


    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click', '.someClass', openModal);
    })

    function openModal(e) {
     e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
      e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;

        alert("show Model")
      //some other code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Set data-target and data-toggle

```
<li class="someClass">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showModal" href="#">Some Text</a>
</li>
```